# Replacing cells with numbers

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is the query for replacing values?

For example in the following table I want  to replace the cells that have text with 1 and the texts that have null with 0.

I searched the forum and found a query for replacing null. How about the other?

SELECT ISNULL(myColumn, 0 ) FROM myTable

[image]

Comment: Use [`CASE` expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)?

Comment: @ Pang I  have not used sql for a long time! and I forgot everything. Now I am doing my research and need data again! Would you please tell me how to write the query for CASE?

Comment: If you click on the link in @Pang's comment, you would find out an explanation on *how to write the query for CASE*.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with CASE WHEN . like below

```
CREATE TABLE #Example(
       value      [nvarchar](50)   NULL
)
GO

INSERT   #Example  (value)   VALUES (null)
INSERT   #Example  (value)   VALUES ('null')
INSERT   #Example  (value)   VALUES ('dsaf')
INSERT   #Example  (value)   VALUES ('INDIA')


select value, case 
    when value is null then 0 
    when value='null' then 0  
    else  1 end value   
from #example

DROP table #Example
```